# Kafka - message not getting consumed from only one of the partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have a single node Kafka service running Kafka 2.13 version. For one of the topics, we have configured 20 partitions and there is just one consumer group consuming from this topic. This setup has been working fine for a long time now. Recently we have been seeing issues w.r.t Kafka rebalancing this consumer group frequently. After a while, the consumers start consuming again, but on one of the partitions, the current offset doesn't move forward at all indicating the messages are stuck in that partition. Other messages from other partitions get consumed without any issues. Logs from Kafka service doesn't show any issue. Any hints on what is going wrong and how to identify / rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation is that the specific partition has a message that takes a long time to process, this could explain both the frequent rebalancing and the stuck offset

Comment: My initial suspect was the same and hence I inspected the message at the current offset using the kafka-console-consumer command. Nothing seems to be different for that message